# Can I run Smarty plugin to Display method?

Tags: smarty

Suppose there is a template:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>{$title}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    {mod name='block' }
    </body>
</html>
```

There is a plugin:

```
function smarty_function_mod($params, &$smarty) {
$core->smarty->assign('title', 'New title'); 
}
```

In the main code:

```
$smarty->assign('title', 'Заголовок');
$smarty->display('template.tpl');
```

So the question – how should I assign a new value for the var title from the plugin, it is performed in the display method? If I do at first the fetch method, and then the display method – everything is OK, but the plugin is run twice. Is there a possibility to do the plugin at first?

Answer (score -1):

Smarty template это php скрипт. Fetch и display просто его выполняют, только fetch возвращает результат, а display выводит. Так что если выполнить fetch, а потом display, то скрипт выполниться дважды - fetch вернет результат с title = 'Заголовок' и вызовет функцию плагина, которая изменит значение переменной (но заголовок в этот момент будет уже обработан). Потом display выведет уже измененный заголовок и опять вызовет функцию плагина.

Вобщем надо вызывать функцию плагина до вызова fetch или display. Можно например поместить ее в начало шаблона, тогда эффект от изменения title будет сразу.

Comment: Да это я все понимаю. Собственно и вопрос, можно ли по другому это сделать? Если поместить в начало шаблона то и код вернется в начало шаблона. Предположим я вывожу новость, соответственно заголовок страницы должен измениться на заголовок новости. p.s. спалился со словом "Заголовок" )))

Comment: нет, так сделать нельзя - открой скомпилированный смарти шаблон и все поймешь. Переменная конкатенируется в строку в том месте, где она стоит в шаблоне. То есть это все равно что $result = "<title>$title</title>"; $result .= pluginFunction(); - на title уже никак не повлиять - он в этот момент уже является просто часть строки результата. То есть тут надо воздействовать на резутат, а не на тайтл.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо за ответ. Значит придется перестраивать всю архитектуру подключения модулей(